# Display probem with Ubuntu Online Accounts

Tags: raspberrypi, online-accounts, 21.04

Running Ubuntu 21.04 on Raspberry Pi 400. When I try to set up a Google or Microsoft Account, the resulting dialog box is garbled (see the following screenshot).

[image: Google Account garbled text]

I've tried adjusting the display settings to no avail.

Comment: I've got the same on a Raspberry Pi 4 B. Haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ubuntu v21 online adding Google account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1382717/ubuntu-v21-online-adding-google-account)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** On the command line, type:

```
$ WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1 gnome-control-center
```

This is a duplicate of [ubuntu v21 online adding Google account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1382717/ubuntu-v21-online-adding-google-account) and I found that [the solution here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1385370) solved the issue I was having on a stock installation of Ubuntu 22.04 Pi.