# ubuntu v21 online adding Google account

Tags: login, google-chrome

When trying to add google account to newly installed v21 of ubuntu, it is listed in st v21 interface when you select the google account the pop up window comes up however the writing seems to look almost overscreened & attempting to write the graphical data on the next line.

the required login detail seems to be present it is just unreadable & thus cannot fill out the google online account details.

Similar thing also occurs with the Microsoft online account when adding into the ubuntu v21.

Screen shots of what is happening.

[image: Online account login displaying a glitched mess]
[image: Other online account login displaying a glitched mess]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?  (There is no "v21")  Are you on Ubuntu 21.04 or Ubuntu 21.10?  Is this a new installation?  Does this occur in other applications?  What CPU/GPU do you have?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu v21.  Ubuntu has both products that use the *year* format (such as Ubuntu Core 20; they are specialist releases intended for *headless* operation) and the far more common *year.month* format (such as Ubuntu 21.04 & Ubuntu 21.10).  They are different products, so which are you using? or are you using a non-Ubuntu or *fake* system?

Comment: Remove any custom themes or icon packs, then try again.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I DO have the answer. It is indeed a compositing error.
I looked at https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeOnlineAccounts/Debugging
and the solution is as follows:

1. Open a terminal on the affected machine
2. On the command line, type: WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1 gnome-control-center
3. Hit
4. This will start the online accounts application
5. Click on "Google" and
6. Behold! Now you get the normal screen and you can enter your credentials

### You may forget the info below

I don't have the answer, but exactly the same issue. Spent several hours on internet trying to find a solution.

My setup:
Raspberry PI 4, Ubuntu 21.10 64 bit ARM (!), Gnome 40.4.0, Wayland.
It is a pristine installation, fully updated but without any extensions, etc.

On online accounts, I can configure the Ubuntu SSO without a problem, but once I try to add my Google-account, I experience **exactly** the same as the original poster.

I would be interested in a solution. Is it the window-manager or compositing that turns the pop-up window into this?

Comment: I had this exact issue on a stock Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS downloaded from the Raspberry Pi download page here https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi and the above answer above works for 22.04 too.